# Why is timezone.now showing a future date when being applied as a default value to DateField in django

Tags: django, django-timezone

Here are the relevant settings in my project:

`settings.py`

```
TIME_ZONE = "US/Mountain"
USE_TZ = True
```

`models.py` (using `timezone.now`)

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(
        default=timezone.now,
        blank=True,
    )

    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
    )
```

If I create a `Submission` at 5PM MST on 03/01/2023 these are the values I get:

- `date_created`: "2023-03-02"
- `datetime_created`: "2023-03-01 17:00:00-07:00"

Why would `date_created` be using the date of the following date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason this happens is because the "date" (without the time) isn't [timezone aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects).

You can see in the [DateField source where Django automatically converts a datetime back to UTC](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fbe850106b2e4b85f838219cb9e1df95fba6c164/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1382-L1383):

```py
    def _check_fix_default_value(self):
        """
        Warn that using an actual date or datetime value is probably wrong;
        it's only evaluated on server startup.
        """
        if not self.has_default():
            return []

        value = self.default
        if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            value = _to_naive(value).date()  # <————— HERE!
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
            pass
        else:
            # No explicit date / datetime value -- no checks necessary
            return []
        # At this point, value is a date object.
        return self._check_if_value_fixed(value)
```

Personally I would use a `DateTimeField` so you keep the timezone information, and just access `.date` when you need it, but you should be able to use `datetime.date.today` (assuming you don't want to use the [`auto_now_add` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for some reason):

```py
import datetime

class Submission(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(
        default=datetime.date.today,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Based on the docs of the link you provided, I'm extremely confused when `_check_fix_default_value` is being run, but that definitely clears up what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `date_created` field to store the correct date of creation, you can modify the default value with this: `default=timezone.now().date()`

The `.date()` method returns the date portion of a DateTime object and this will set the `date_created` field to "2023-03-01" (In your case - New DB Entry will require), which is the correct date of creation.

So you can try the code as per below:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(
        default=timezone.now().date(),
        blank=True,
    )

    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
    )
```

The reason of the date_created field is set to "`2023-03-02`" is that the DateField type only stores the date, without the time information so when you set the default value to `timezone.now` it will take the time zone information specified in your settings.py file.
As you have set the time zone to "US/Mountain" on `settings.py` file, which is 7 hours behind UTC. Since the TIME_ZONE setting was set to "US/Mountain" when the data entry happens at 5 PM MST on `03/01/2023`, the actual date in UTC was `02/01/2023` (time difference between MST and UTC). This is the reason why the value for date_created was set to "`2023-03-02`" for you.
[You can check timezone converter](https://savvytime.com/converter/utc-to-mst)